# Change Text on Open and Close of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

Currently my navigation bar text is Menu, and when it is clicked I want Menu to change to Close, and when menu is closed it should go back to saying Menu

Here is my Current Code - On click it does change to 'Close' but doesn't change back:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".menu-Trigger").click(function() {

        jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function() { 
             jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-Expanded").css("display", "");

          });
        $(".menu-Trigger").html("Close");
    });
});
```

HTML and CSS Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Arshdeep Soni</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                background-image: url(Final6Lower.jpg);
                background-size: auto 100%;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;

            }

            .nav-menu li, .nav-menu a{
                display: inline-flex;
                color: rgb(137, 134, 134);
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: Raleway;
                padding-right: 15px;
                font-size: 12px;
                letter-spacing: 7px;

            }
            .nav-menu {
                margin-top: 25px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .nav-menu li, .nav-menu a:hover {
                color:white;
            }

            .socialIcons img {
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
                opacity: 0.4;
                filter: alpha(opacity=40);
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            icons img {
                position:relative;
                display: inline;
                margin-right: 0 auto;
                margin-left: 0 auto;
            }

            .icons {
                text-align: center;
                position:absolute;
                bottom:10px;
                left:0;
                width: 100%;

            }

            .socialIcons img:hover {
                opacity:1;
                color:white;
            }

            .menu-Trigger {
                display:none;
            }

            div.nav-menu ul {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            div.nav-menu ul li {
                list-style: none;
            }


            @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

                .menu-Trigger {
                    display: block;
                    color:white;
                    background-color: black;
                    padding:10px;
                    text-align: center;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    font-family: raleway;
                }

                div.nav-menu ul li {
                    display:block;
                    float:none;
                    padding:8px;
                    background-color: black;
                }

                div.nav-menu {
                    display:none;
                }

                div.nav-Expanded {
                    display: block;
                }
            }


        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="header">
        </div>                    

        <span class="menu-Trigger" align="center" >Menu</span>
        <div class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=#>HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>VIDEOS</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>IMAGES</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

            <div class="icons">
                <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.youtube.com" title="Subscribe on YouTube" alt="Arshdeep on YouTube"><img src="youtube.png"/></a>
        <a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.instagram.com/ArshSoni" title="Subscribe!" alt="Arshdeep Soni"><img src="instagram.png" /></a>
<a class="socialIcons" href="http://www.facebook.com/MagicArsh" title="Arshdeep Soni on Facebook" alt="Facebook"><img src="fb.png" /></a>
                <a class="socialIcons" href="http://twitter.com/ArshSoni" title="Follow Arshdeep on Twitter" alt="Twitter"><img src="twitter.png" /></a>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a boolean, to check whether the menu is open or not and then, depending on the result of that boolean, change the text.

Comment: What is the `.nav-Expanded` class used for? Is it soley used to tell if the menu is open or closed or does it also have styling associated with it?

Comment: This can be easily accomplished with CSS (and a small markup change). If you're interested in that, please show your HTML.

Comment: @isherwood Code added!

Comment: Here's a quick 'n dirty start. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/rLcco746/ Protips: Use camelCase or hyph-ens for your class names, not both. It's too hard to remember what you capitalized otherwise. Also, single quotes for JS, double for HTML. It makes things much simpler when they get combined. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are simply missing the if expression checking whether your menu is expanded or not. Not sure about your html, but this might work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".menu-Trigger").click(function() {

        jQuery(".nav-menu").slideToggle(400, function() { 
             jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-Expanded").css("display", "");

          });
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("nav-Expanded"))
            $(".menu-Trigger").html("Close");
        else
            $(".menu-Trigger").html("Menu");
    });
});
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, The menu bar doesn't even open then

Comment: Check the console for error messages and maybe edit your html into your question - Also close the parentese around if condition, I made a typo

Comment: After seeing your html, I think this should be working. I edited the answer to fix a typo, try again.